Нет файла /config/initializers/mime_types.rb
Ребят, установил гем, прописал команды bundler, но файла /config/initializers/mime_types.rb нет. Что делать в таком случае? Как добавить в проект данный файл. У меня стоит Rails 7.2.2.1.

Очень сложно понять суть вопроса, хотелось бы подробностей и контекста. Какой гем установил? Какую задачу решаете и что пытаетесь получить в результате? Что мешает создать файл руками и заполнить его нужными типами?

Гем mimemagic, сейчас мне нужен делать так, что я мог скачать xls файл. А чтоб в проекте сделать данный тип файла, нужен этот файл. Его сейчас у меня нет, хотя даже bundle прописывал, чтоб его в проект добавить. Если лично добавить, он ругается)

Всё равно не очень понятно. Для того, что распарсить или сгенерить xls он не нужен. Он используется для определения типа файла, но если вы загружаете только xls, то зачем бы он? И да, на что ругается?

Сейчас добавил случайно этот файл, теперь сработало) Теперь буду узнавать, почему так случилось)
